# Ошибка: ORA-00439: Не задействована функциональная возможность: Fine-grained access control Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Хочу сделать защиту на уровне записей (*row level security*) для таблицы `Good`.

Создал функцию-фильтр:

```
create or replace function policy_func (p_schema varchar2, p_object varchar2)
return varchar2 is
begin
   if (user = 'USER_ ') then
      return 'price > 700';
   end if;
   return 'price < 200';
end;
```

Но не получается добавить политику:

```
Begin
DBMS_RLS.add_policy (
   object_schema => 'system',
   object_name  => 'good',
   policy_name  => 'clients_policy',
   function_schema => 'system',
   policy_function  => 'policy_func',
   statement_types => 'select, insert, update, delete',
   update_check => true
);
End;
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
2020-12-03 02:02:51] [67000][439]
[2020-12-03 02:02:51]   ORA-00439: Не задействована функциональная возможность: Fine-grained 
access control
[2020-12-03 02:02:51]   ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_RLS_INT", line 23
[2020-12-03 02:02:51]   ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_RLS", line 54
[2020-12-03 02:02:51]   ORA-06512: на  line 2
[2020-12-03 02:02:51] Position: 0
```

В чем проблема ?

---

PS моя версия БД 12.2.0.1.0

Comment: Укажите версию БД. На 19.3 не воспроизводится.

Comment: вот моя версия 12.2.0.1.0

Comment: На 12.2.0.1 тоже работает как часы. Когда конкретно ошибка возникает?  _Добавил политику_, звучит так, как будто добавлена без ошибок.

Comment: При создании политики. Исправил

Comment: И чем создаёте,  т.е. каким клиентом?

Comment: Через  PyCharm подключился к Oracle

Comment: в Enterprise Edition версии такой возможности ( rls ) нету вроде бы

Comment: Попробуйте в sqlplus, заодно и строку версии полностью опубликуйте. Я проверил на - Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: А можно узнасть, какая причина отката к самой первой версии?

Comment: Видимо, я нажал на "править", думая, что это тоже самое что принять правки,но нет,и сохранил старую версию таким образом)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исключение:

> ORA-00439: Не задействована функциональная возможность: Fine-grained access control

или:

> ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Fine-grained access control

Вызывается в случае, если функциональная опция недоступна в утановленной версии/редакции БД.

Проверить, включенна ли опция, можно запросом:

```
select parameter, value 
from v$option where parameter='Fine-grained access control'
/
PARAMETER                        VALUE 
-------------------------------- ------
Fine-grained access control      TRUE
```

Если `value=false`, то опция недоступна, а если `true`, будет работать:

```
SQL> begin dbms_rls.add_policy (
  2      object_schema => 'system',
  3      object_name  => 'good',
  4      policy_name  => 'clients_policy',
  5      function_schema => 'system',
  6      policy_function  => 'policy_func',
  7      statement_types => 'select, insert, update, delete',
  8      update_check => true); end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```